# Spring boot multiple scheduler with same cron expression not working

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, cron, scheduler

I am developing an application that will run under spring boot context with tomcat. This project run multiple scheduler based on configured cron expression.

In my application there are 3 scheduler run on every 5 minutes and following is the cron expression 0 0/5 * * * * So I believe all 3 scheduler is run parallel but only one scheduler is execute and other 2 are skip.

Following is my code base

```
@Component 
public class Scheduler1 {

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * *", zone = "${scheduler.timezone}")
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Scheduler1 execute");
    }
}

@Component 
public class Scheduler2 {

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * *", zone = "${scheduler.timezone}")
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Scheduler2 execute");
    }
}

@Component 
public class Scheduler3 {

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * *", zone = "${scheduler.timezone}")
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Scheduler3 execute");
    }
}
```

I am aware that we can use the @async to run all scheduler. But without using @async do we have any alternative way.

Comment: Are those two which are not running in the same package as working one? If no then probably their packages are not scanned by SpringBoot

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but no luck. I created 3 scheduler class in same package as shown in question and ran it without `@async`. Everything works fine for me. I believe that the problem lies somewhere else and not with `@Scheduler`.